# QtCreator project Menubar & code portability

Tags: qt

As we know programe written in QT is able to port across platform.

At present i am developing programme using QTcreator, here i can directly edit the Menubar & enter item to it.
But the code for this is not atall visible in .cpp files.

like shown here :---
http://codeprogress.com/cpp/libraries/qt/QMenuBarAddMenu.php#.UXYeyaL-EfE

1> Where is the code for this Menubar ?

2> Also another question is that is the GUI program written in (QTcreator in windows) is able to run on Linux host ?

3> Does there QT creator for Linux also ?

Please suggest on this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) In Qt Creator, click on `QMenuBar` and press "F1" or navigate to "Help > Context Help", while the cursor is on `QMenuBar`, or you can press "F2" or navigate to "Tools > C++ > Follow Symbol under Cursor", and it will take you to where QMenuBar is defined.  The right click menu is very helpful, too.

2) Probably through `wine`.  Though most people would recompile it for other OS's... so download Qt SDK for linux onto a linux distribution, and build it there.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/deployment.html

3)  Yes.

http://qt-project.org/downloads

http://qt-project.org/downloads#qt-creator

But be sure to also get the SDK for linux, too.

http://qt-project.org/downloads#qt-lib

Hope that helps.

Comment: following option is coming disabled -- Follow Symbol under Cursor  -- not able to see the code ?

Comment: Qt Creator might not have a Qt SDK in its settings yet.  Check "Tools > Options > Build and Run > Qt Versions".

Comment: Also the implementation of `QMenuBar` is not important, the interface is, and it is well documented in the help.  Also you can see it online. http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmenubar.html